# PackagingOptions/packaging issue after upgrading AGP (8.1.1)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Project was upgraded to gradle 8.1 and AGP 8.1.1.

After that, it is not possible to sync project with packagingOptions block of code:

```
packagingOptions.resources.apply {
        excludes.addAll(
            listOf(
                "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES",
                "META-INF/LICENSE",
                "META-INF/LICENSE.txt",
                "META-INF/license.txt",
                "META-INF/NOTICE",
                "META-INF/NOTICE.txt",
                "META-INF/notice.txt",
                "META-INF/ASL2.0"
            )
        )
    }
```

The result is:

```
Unable to find method ''com.android.build.api.dsl.ResourcesPackagingOptions com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.getResources()''
'com.android.build.api.dsl.ResourcesPackagingOptions com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.getResources()'
```

If I use packaging instead:

```
packaging {
        resources {
            excludes.addAll(
                listOf(
                    "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES",
                    "META-INF/LICENSE",
                    "META-INF/LICENSE.txt",
                    "META-INF/license.txt",
                    "META-INF/NOTICE",
                    "META-INF/NOTICE.txt",
                    "META-INF/notice.txt",
                    "META-INF/ASL2.0"
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
Unresolved reference: packaging
```

However, is it not highlighted red or something like that.

Android studio is also behaves strange:

1. All android block is red
2. Or it reports "Code insight unavailable"
3. Reports "internal syntax error"
   All of them is in build.gradle.src file of app

Current config:

1. Android Studio Hedgehog
2. AGP 8.1.1 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1)
3. Gradle 8.1. (distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip)

I cleared and invalidated cache, cleared .gradle and tried to clear everything, but problem still exists

Comment: facing same issue do you got any solution?

Comment: @geek919, check the marked answer, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue for months. I just added

```
classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1")
```

to my top-level build.gradle and it now compiles.